# "Беспокоит то что" — нужна ли запятая?

Tags: запятые

*Беспокоит то(,) что я не смогу тебя ни с кем делить.*

Answer (score 1):

Да, запятая нужна. Указательное местоимение *то* прикрепляет к себе придаточную часть, которая конкретизирует его значение.

> *Беспокоит то, что я не смогу тебя ни с кем делить.*